# Automapper N to N

Tags: c#, database, postgresql, visual-studio, automapper

I have these Database entities that I want to map:

Products

```
public partial class Products
{
    public Products()
    {
        SalesProducts = new HashSet<SalesProducts>();
    }

    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public float Price { get; set; }
    public int Quant { get; set; }

    public ICollection<SalesProducts> SalesProducts { get; set; }
}
```

Sales

```
public partial class Sales
{
    public Sales()
    {
        SalesProducts = new HashSet<SalesProducts>();
    }

    public int SaleId { get; set; }
    public int? ClientId { get; set; }
    public float TotalPrice { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Date { get; set; }

    public Clients Client { get; set; }
    public ICollection<SalesProducts> SalesProducts { get; set; }
}
```

SalesProducts

```
public partial class SalesProducts
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public int SaleId { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }

    public Products Product { get; set; }
    public Sales Sale { get; set; }
}
```

And these models:

Products

```
public class Products
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public float Price { get; set; }
    public int Quant { get; set; }
}
```

Sales

```
public class Sales
{
    public int SaleId { get; set; }
    public int ClientId { get; set; }
    public string ClientFirstName { get; set; }
    public string ClientLastName { get; set; }
    public float TotalPrice { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Date { get; set; }
}
```

SalesDetails

```
public class SalesDetails
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

All sales mapping:

```
public class SalesProfiles : Profile
{
    public SalesProfiles()
    {
        CreateMap<DataModels.Sales, Models.Sales>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.SaleId, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.SaleId))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.ClientId, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Client.ClientId))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.ClientFirstName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Client.FirstName))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.ClientLastName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Client.LastName))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Date, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Date))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.TotalPrice, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.TotalPrice));

        CreateMap<DataModels.Products, Models.SalesDetails>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.ProductId, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.ProductId))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.ProductName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.ProductName))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Description, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Description))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Quantity, opt => opt.Ignore());

        CreateMap<DataModels.SalesProducts, Models.SalesDetails>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.ProductId, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Product.ProductId))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.ProductName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Product.ProductName))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Description, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Product.Description))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Quantity, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Quantity));
    }
}
```

Products mapping

```
public class ProductsProfiles : Profile
{
    public ProductsProfiles()
    {
        CreateMap<Models.Products, BindingModels.Products>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.ProductName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.ProductName))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Description, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Description))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Quant, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Quant))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Price, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Price))
            .ReverseMap();

        CreateMap<Models.Products, DataModels.Products>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.ProductId, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.ProductId))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.ProductName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.ProductName))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Description, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Description))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Quant, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Quant))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Price, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Price))
            .ReverseMap();

        CreateMap<BindingModels.Products, DataModels.Products>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.ProductName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.ProductName))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Description, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Description))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Quant, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Quant))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Price, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Price))
            .ReverseMap();

        CreateMap<DataModels.Products, Models.Products>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.ProductId, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.ProductId))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.ProductName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.ProductName))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Description, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Description))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Quant, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Quant))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Price, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Price))
            .ReverseMap();
    }
}
```

This is a n to n relationship between sales and products. Does somebody knows how can I map this properly with automapper?

I already tried to map but it is always saying that products properties are not mapped

Comment: Can you please post the code which you have tried (as per your comment -  I already tried to map but it is always saying that products properties are not mapped)?

Comment: Already posted. It says that product name and description are not mapped

Comment: @JoãoSilva The mappings is correct. Are you sure that this is the whole mappings configuration you have? Show us the one that use Product?

Comment: @CodeNotFound All mappeds posted

Comment: Great :) _that products properties are not mapped_  The exception message also contains which properties are involved to this issue. Look at the exception message and the Inner Exception and you'll see the list of properties.

Comment: @CodeNotFound the properties are ProductName and Description. The error occurs when make the map from SalesProducts to SalesDetails. :)

Comment: Is there any exception being thrown? Or When you say they are not mapped then where are you validating?

Comment: Is an exception being thrown